# Cannot convert Class to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection

I'm trying to convert my class `AllStock` to `ObservableCollection<AllStock> stockList` but I get the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection.Add(Haze.AllStock)' has some invalid arguments

Here is my coding:

I create my Observable Collection -

```
private ObservableCollection<AllStock> _stockList;
public ObservableCollection<AllStock> stockList
{
    get
    {
        if (_stockList == null)
            _stockList = new ObservableCollection<AllStock>();
        return _stockList;
    }
}
```

Inside my method -

```
var allStock = await service.GetSysproStockAsync();
var stock = allStock.Select(x =>
new AllStock
{
    Id = x.Id,
    ...
    MaterialThickness = x.MaterialThickness
});

stockList.Add(stock); //Error here - I want to add my 'var stock' to my ObservableCollection
dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = stockList;
```

Why would it be throwing out this error?

Comment: `var stock = allStock.Select(....` creates a new IEnumerable of allstock. you cannot add a List to your collection. you have to add them with a foreach loop or something like that.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Sweet man that makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Linq's **Select** method returns an **IEnumerable** but your **stockList.Add** has no overload for this datatype (only **AllStock**).

```
foreach(AllStock aStock in stock)
    stockList.Add(aStock)
```

should work. The ObservableCollection unfortunatley doesn't have a **AddRange** method like the **List<>**

Answer (score 1):

The Add() for ObservableCollection requires a List so you need to provide a List instead.

Comment: Not the constructor, the Add method. The constructor has an overload for IEnumerables